# Why isn't my animation element centered?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm stuck on this for so long, why the car isn't swerve around the middle line with my animation? it seems like a bit off to the right?

```css
.car {
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #f00;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  animation: swerve 2s linear infinite;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes swerve {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
  }
}
.road {
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.road-middle {
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='road'>
  <span class="road-middle"></span>
  <div class='car'></div>
</div>
```

Also how to control the length of the middle's border?

Comment: i saw you accepted an answer bellow. it's a good one. but it uses fixed measurements to center the car ( pixels ), and well...if the car changes it's `width` this code won't work, better to center the absolute div ( `.car` ) with `left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto` , and so , no matter what the width of the `.car` is, it will always stay centered.

see my answer below ( solved the dotted line problem too )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.car` is not centered on the `.road` , change the css for the `.car` to this

```
.car{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

to change the length of the `road-middle` dotted line, do not rotate it, but instead make it with `width:0` and `height:100%`, use this css :

```
.road-middle{
    border: 1px dotted #fff;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width:0px;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

**See snippet below**

```css
.car {
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #f00;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  animation: swerve 2s linear infinite;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes swerve {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
  }
}
.road {
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.road-middle {
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width:0px;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class='road'>
  <span class="road-middle"></span>
  <div class='car'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `left:50%` but don't calculate the car width. To fix this, you can alter the animation like this:

```css
.car {
    width: 40px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #f00;
    left: 50%;
    animation: swerve 2s linear infinite;
    top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}


@keyframes swerve {
 0% {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 }
  
    25% {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
 }
      

 75% {
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
 }
  
    100% {
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
}

.road{
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  height:500px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.road-middle{
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='road'>
  <span class="road-middle"></span>
 <div class='car'></div>

</div>
```

To control the length of the road-middle element, you can do the following:

```
.road-middle{
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
  display: block;

  /* remove the rotation */

  /*position the line */
    position: absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 1px);

  /*controll the length of the line */
  height:200px;
  top:150px;
}
```

```css
.car {
    width: 40px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #f00;
    left: 50%;
    animation: swerve 2s linear infinite;
    top: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}


@keyframes swerve {
 0% {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 }
  
    25% {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
 }
      

 75% {
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
 }
  
    100% {
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
}

.road{
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  height:500px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.road-middle{
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
    display: block;
  
  /* remove the rotation */
  
  /*position the line */
    position: absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 1px);
  
  /*controll the length of the line */
  height:200px;
  top:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='road'>
  <span class="road-middle"></span>
 <div class='car'></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`left: calc(50% - 20px);`

You are not subtracting the car width

Answer (score 1):

If you comment this 2 lines

```
 transform: translate(-100%, 0); 
 animation: swerve 2s linear infinite;
```

you block isn't centered..

So replace by (or fix your first problem)

```
@keyframes swerve {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `left: 50%` aligns the leftmost edge of your element with the center. To align vertical center of your element with container's center you need to add negative margin equal to half that element's width, which pushes it back to left a little. E.g. here I have added `margin-left: -20px;` to your car and now it is in center:

```css
.car {
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #f00;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  animation: swerve 2s linear infinite;
  top: 10%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes swerve {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
  }
}
.road {
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.road-middle {
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='road'>
  <span class="road-middle"></span>
  <div class='car'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well...if the car changes it's `width` this code won't work, better to center the absolute div ( `.car` ) width `left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto` , and so , no matter what the with of the `.car` is, it will always stay centered

Comment: @MihaiT Yes you're right. But sometimes it depends on the case. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have mentioned the with  40px and moved the car from left by 50% which means your car is situated at 50%+40px to right. Try following code.

```css
.car {
  width: 18%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #f00;
  left: 41%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  animation: swerve 2s linear infinite;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes swerve {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
  }
}
.road {
  width: 200px;
  background: black;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.road-middle {
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='road'>
  <span class="road-middle"></span>
  <div class='car'></div>
</div>
```